# Windows 8.1 doesn't remember window sizes/positions when I switch off my monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, nvidia-geforce

I have three monitors connected to my Windows 8.1 PC. One of them is connected by HDMI, one by DisplayPort and one by DVI (my GeForce GTX 780 has these three connectors). I distribute my windows over the three monitors (most of them maximized) and I'd like them to stay there.

The three monitors don't have the same size. I'm using two of them in Pivot mode (portrait), and one of them in standard (landscape) mode.

Sometimes I turn off the monitors (by plugging their power source) but let the PC run. When I switch the monitors back on, many windows are on another monitor than before, or they have changed their size, even though they were maximized.

**Is there any way to prevent this?**

- Some way of telling the graphics card that it shouldn't treat the monitors as disconnected?
- Some way of telling Windows it should rearrange the windows as soon as the monitors are running again?

Comment: What pisses me off is when you are all OCD about window positions and sizes (like I am) and when a Metro app opens (whether by choice or as a result of an unknown default file association) when you switch back to desktop it ALWAYS screws up your positioning and sizing of windows!